# Write a loop that should generate multiplication questions with single digit random integers

Tags: java

I'm stuck at the part where I loop back into: "yes" - I want to continue or "no" - I'd like to exit.

I'm aware I would need to display an if? to display results only if you exit the program

```
    //Input your display and questions:
    int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10 +1); 
    int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
    int answer = 0; 
    int correctCount=0;
    int count= 0;
    //Scanner object input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    //Swap numbers if number2 is bigger than number 1
    if (num1 < num2) {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }


    //OUTPUT DISPLAY QUESTION: What is num1 + num2 = ? 
    System.out.print("What is "+num1 + " * " + num2 + " = "); 
    answer = input.nextInt(); 


    //If answer is correct display: Good Job! Your got it right
    if (answer == (num1 * num2)) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Good job! You got it right!\n"); 
        correctCount++; //Increases correct count for answer correct!
    } 
    else 
        System.out.println("You got it wrong, try again!\n" +num1 + " * " +num2+ " should be " + (num1 * num2)); 

    count++;        
    System.out.print("Enter Y to continue or N to exit: \n"); //Do you want to continue             
    System.out.println("\nYou got " +correctCount+ " out of "+count + " answer correct"); //Displays Correct with total# of questions
    }
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to know more about how to use this site, and how to improve the questions you make. Your question lacks clarity: it's not clear what you are asking, less clear what you want to achieve. I suggest you to review the question, and make editions in order to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm unable to figure out where I put a do while statement into solving the program.  Im trying to have this program repeat multiplication questions until further instructed not to

Answer (score 0):

You have just to use a `while` loop to make the app loop until the user enter a character other than `y`.

also, try to use `try-with-resource` to avoid source leak with `scanner` object

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Input your display and questions:
    int answer = 0;
    int correctCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String continueStr = "yes";

    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (continueStr.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            // Scanner object input
            int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);

            // Swap numbers if number2 is bigger than number 1
            if (num1 < num2) {
                int temp = num1;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = temp;
            }

            // OUTPUT DISPLAY QUESTION: What is num1 + num2 = ?
            System.out.print("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2 + " = ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();

            // If answer is correct display: Good Job! Your got it right
            if (answer == (num1 * num2)) {
                System.out.println("Good job! You got it right!\n");
                correctCount++; // Increases correct count for answer correct!
            } else {
                System.out.println("You got it wrong, try again!\n" + num1 + " * " + num2 + " should be " + (num1 * num2));
            }
            count++;

            System.out.print("\nEnter Yes to continue or No to exit: \n"); // Do you want to continue
            continueStr = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("\nYou got " + correctCount + " out of " + count + " answer correct"); // Displays Correct with total# of questions
    }
}
```

Comment: It works and repeat the questions, but I need to be able to put yes continue or no stop

Comment: so it would display  9 * 5 = 45 correct then it would be like Enter Y to continue or N to exit

Comment: Is there a way I could display the count only when you say NO? to exit like would i put if (false) then ....above the count statement?

Comment: Sorry to be so picky. When i type in yes i still display the count...It looks great but could i remove it all together and only display the count statement at the bottom only when i was to type N or No

Comment: @JaredPaul, yes the last update do like this, just after you typed string other than `yes` the count will displayed, So the `count` will appear once and the app will exit.